# How to avoid Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the following code to display terms of two taxonomies from another post:

```
$featured_post = get_field('about_game');
if( $featured_post ): 
            $permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post->ID );
            $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail ($featured_post->ID );
            
            
            $terms_genre = get_the_terms( $featured_post->ID, 'genre' );
            foreach( $terms_genre as $term_genre ) {
            if( $term_genre->count > 0 )
            echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( $term_genre ) .'">'. $term_genre->name .'</a>';

}
            
            $terms_developer = get_the_terms( $featured_post->ID, 'developer' );
            foreach( $terms_developer as $term_developer ) {
            if( $term_developer->count > 0 )
            echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( $term_developer ) .'">'. $term_developer->name .'</a>';

}
```

The problem is, where there is no single term, I get the following warning:

```
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, bool given in
```

How to avoid this warning when I have no terms?

Comment: Check whether you have terms before running the foreach? Surround it with `if ($terms_genre) {` for example.

Comment: get_the_terms will return false, when it finds no terms - typical WP nonsense :-), it should rather return an _empty_ array then (in which case there would be no problem here to begin with.) But since it doesn't behave in such a _logical_ way, you'll have to check first then - a simple `if($terms_genre) { foreach(...) }` should be enough here already. (You could check if it actually _is_ an array, but that is rather over the top in such a place.)

Comment: if($terms_genre) solves the problem, thanks guys!